# Input App recording tracks

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, mergin-maps

Is there a way of recording tracks in Lutra Consulting's app in the background? I cannot reckord my track and putting point records in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet [1]. If you record a track, the app will be in the foreground and blocks you from recording other features.

[1] https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues/500